# Pandas: Kernel unexpectedly dies after attempting join() two large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kernel, jupyter-lab

I am trying to join two datasets that share the same index by using:

```
merged_data = df1.join(df2)
```

However, the kernel keeps dying. I've attempted restarting my notebook (jupyter lab) but I think it's related to one of the data frames being about 2GB...

About df1

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 97812 entries, XXXX to XXXX
Data columns (total 19 columns):
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3), object(14)
memory usage: 14.9+ MB
```

about df2

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 13888745 entries, XXXX to XXXX
Data columns (total 18 columns):
dtypes: int64(16), object(2)
memory usage: 2.0+ GB
```

**How can I make this work?**

I do need all the entries and columns. The dataframes don't share columns in common besides the index.

If it is worth knowing... I am using a MacBook Pro (Early 2015) with 2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 (processor) and 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3 (memory)

Comment: This most likely means that you are running out of memory and your operating system kills the kernel. Try to take increasingly large `head(n=x)` parts of the data frames (say `x` = 10, 1000, 10000, etc) and note down how the memory use changes after merging the heads; also look at the output of merged heads and confirm that this is really the way you want it to be.

Comment: Is there any remote way of increasing it? Not so educated on the memory department yet. Wondering if using a web server somehow helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is indeed due to your laptop running out of memory, you could try to use something like [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/).

You can convert your pandas dataframes into dask dataframes using `dask.dataframe.from_pandas`. Then use the `.join` method of the dask dataframes, like regular pandas.